# MySQL query runs okay on test machine, but fails on ISP server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am testing with MySQL on my home machine using an Apache server under XAMPP with the MySQL settings: Server: localhost via TCP/IP, version 5.5.16.

I have a query: `SELECT * FROM project WHERE refno = $refno;`

This works perfectly on my test machine. When I try the same thing on my ISP server, which has the following settings: Server: localhost via UNIX socket, version 5.0.92

I get the message:

> "supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource"

Is the problem the difference in the settings? Is there anything I can do to get it working?

Comment: You need to post some code, because that query in itself is not really valid.

Comment: is it working in phpMyAdmin on the server?
are you properly connected to database on the server?

Comment: There is some error executing your query, you might be connected to the wrong database. Try checking `mysql_error()` after you execute the query. Generally this is done by adding ` or die(mysql_error());` after the statement. The error message should help you figuring out whats wrong.

Comment: Is this error in a script, or in PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: @stefgosselin it seems to be an error in phpMyAdmin

Comment: @Cylindric here is the code: 'code'<?php
 
include("dbinfo.inc.php");
mysql_connect("localhost","$username","$password") or die("Error: ".mysqlerror());
mysql_select_db("autoroller"); 
$refno = $_GET['refno'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM project WHERE refno = '$refno'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 
    $refno = $row['refno'];
    $cust_code = $row['cust_code'];
    $lead_status = $row['lead_status'];
    $closed_status = $row['closed_status'];
    $rep_code = $row['rep_code'];
 etc...

Comment: @AVee the connection worked ok It is the query where the problem is, and as I say, that is working on my local server.

Comment: If the query works on local, it should work as is on remote server. Are all your variables populated ok?  Have you dumped a query to screen and try running in MySQL client or phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @stefgosselin yes I did run the query in the phpMyAdmin and it worked successfully. I put in an error routine after the query and this is the message:Error Number: 1046
Error Description: No database selected
Error Time: 16:12:31, 19th December, 2011
Client: AutoRoller
Script: /autoroller/php/edit_project.php
Line: 
Query: SELECT * FROM project WHERE refno = '18'
Processes: 1932331 Processlist 0
It says no database selected. But how did it get past the error routine on the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you first make absolutely sure you have a valid database connection. Look for [mysql_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) in your script, and make sure it is being passed the proper parameters.  Look for the code examples on the man page to see how to add die() calls to catch any problems. Using die() is not a practice I would recommend on production code, though. You would usually want to catch and log errors, instead of having the script die.

Once you have made sure your connection returns a `ressource`, if it still chokes on you make sure you are sending the proper parameter (database name) to  [mysql_select_db](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php).

Once these forementioned two functions play nice, your query should execute no problem.

Hope that helps, good-luck.

Comment: I am calling this php script  from another php script:

Comment: Sorry guys for wasting your time. Most of the answers were correct. I wasn't accessing the database, and when I put in an error routine on the query it was picked up.  I had overwritten my dbinfo.inc.php with the wrong file when I uploaded my php scripts. I am surprised that the error routine on the connect didn't flag it.

Comment: Actually it isn't fixed. When I go in again I now get the message I inserted:

Comment: The problem seems to be that I have an include dbinfo.inc.php '<?
$username="root";
$password="xxxxxxxxx";
$database="yyyyyyyyy";
?> ' which works on my local server. I obviously modify the username and password when I put it onto the ISP server. It then doesn't work. If, however, I paste the username, password and database variables directly into the code, the connection and query work. It seems that the tags <? ?> are allowed within a php file on my local server but not on the ISP one, which is UNIX. Is this true and will I have to amend code in my php files every time I upload them?

Comment: *Maybe* try with the suggested `shebang`: `<?php`, not sure it will help though.

Comment: Good grief! You are so right! That's all it was, Thanks a million.